# Unable to add data to Firebase database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have created a node with name `Users`. I want to create a child node with name of the `Uid` of the user that register himself and store his/her all profile info in that child node.

It should happen only if user has been successfully registered to database. So I have used following code:

```
                        mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(user.getEmail(), password)
                                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                                        Log.d("MainActivity", "signIn:onComplete:" + task.isSuccessful());

                                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                            DatabaseReference userDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
                                            userDatabaseReference.child(task.getResult().getUser().getUid())
                                                    .setValue(user).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                                @Override
                                                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                                    Toast.makeText(ResetPassword.this, "user registred to database", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                    Intent intent = new Intent(ResetPassword.this, MainActivity.class);
                                                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                                                    startActivity(intent);
                                                }
                                            });

                                        } else {
                                            Toast.makeText(ResetPassword.this, "Registration Failed",
                                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        }
                                    }
                                });
```

But my code is not working. User is registered successfully, but no child is created in the database. Which should be created with the name of the Uid of the user.

When I added breakpoints as shown here:

[image]

I found that compiler goes directly to line 106 after line no 82 without executing any line in between, but still it calls the MainActivity which is called inside on complete.

I don't understand how is this happening. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Change
 `userDatabaseReference.child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).setValue(userInfo)`
to

```
userDatabaseReference.child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).push().setValue(userInfo)
```

Comment: That will generate a child with a push id inside the uid node. I don't think that's what the OP wants.

Comment: Then just use .set() instead of .push()

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the `FirebaseAuthentication.currentUser` hasn't been initialized yet. Try getting it's uid from the Task that is passed as parameter to the `onComplete` method:

```
if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        userDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
                        userDatabaseReference.child(task.getResult().getUser().getUid()).setValue(userInfo).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                Toast.makeText(context, "user registred to database", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        });

                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Update `onComplete()` of your completion listener to see what the failure reason is:

```
userDatabaseReference.child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).setValue(userInfo)
        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "user registred to database", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            System.out.println("onComplete: " + task.getException().getMessage());
        }
    }
});
```

Possibly a problem with your database security rules.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the problem was with connection to Firebase. I had not logged in android studio with same account as Firebase thats why my was not able to communicate with Firebase.